# Python weird [n chars] encoding error?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, encoding

I have a seemingly dumb and simple bug, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. In my test, when I compare two dictionaries, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to_my_app/tests/test_unit.py", line 120, in test_destroy_data
    self.assertEqual(obsolete_data, expected_obsolete_data)
AssertionError: {'cou[45 chars]es': {<Category: Test Category>}, 'beers': {<Beer: Test Beer>}} != {'cou[45 chars]es': {<Category: Test Category>}, 'beers': {<Beer: Test Beer>}}
  {'beers': {<Beer: Test Beer>},
   'categories': {<Category: Test Category>},
   'countries': {<Country: Test Country>}}
```

Django 2.0, Python 3.5

My method:

```
def destroy_data(self):
    """
    Remove entries not in the csv file.
    """
    obsolete_data = {
        'beers': set(Beer.objects.all()) ^ set(self.beer_list),
        'categories': set(Category.objects.all()) ^ set(self.category_list),
        'countries': set(Country.objects.all()) ^ set(self.country_list),
    }

    for data in obsolete_data:
        [obj.delete() for obj in obsolete_data[data]]

    return obsolete_data
```

My test:

```
def test_destroy_data(self):
    """
    Remove old entries.
    """
    self.importer.import_data(destroy=False)
    obsolete_data = self.importer.destroy_data()
    expected_obsolete_data = {
        'countries': {self.country},
        'categories': {self.category},
        'beers': {self.beer},
    }
    self.assertEqual(obsolete_data, expected_obsolete_data)
```

When I inspect these two values in my debugger, they're both same, or at least they print out that way. I've tried writing keys in unicode, but I get the same error. Why does this **[45 chars]** pop up?

**UPDATE**

I've set maxDiff to None while using self.assertDictEqual, and I do get the whole error output, but the error stays the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to_my_app/tests/test_unit.py", line 124, in test_destroy_data
    self.assertDictEqual(obsolete_data, expected_obsolete_data)
AssertionError: {'cat[35 chars]>}, 'beers': {<Beer: Test Beer>}, 'countries':[22 chars]ry>}} != {'cat[35 chars]>}, 'countries': {<Country: Test Country>}, 'b[22 chars]er>}}
  {'beers': {<Beer: Test Beer>},
   'categories': {<Category: Test Category>},
   'countries': {<Country: Test Country>}}
```

Comment: Pick out the various elements in the objects you are comparing and ignore the ones that are indeed equal. You should eventually end up with two simple objects which are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, I've figured out the problem. I deleted these instances from the database, but they're still loaded in memory. So when I compare them to the return data, they're different objects, even though they hold the same data (except one instance.id is None, the other is 1).
So I had to manually test out specific attributes:

```
self.importer.import_data(destroy=False)
obsolete_data = self.importer.destroy_data()
expected_obsolete_data = {
    'countries': [self.country, ],
    'categories': [self.category, ],
    'beers': [self.beer, ],
}

self.assertEqual(
    obsolete_data['countries'][0].name,
    expected_obsolete_data['countries'][0].name
)
self.assertEqual(
    obsolete_data['categories'][0].name,
    expected_obsolete_data['categories'][0].name
)
self.assertEqual(
    obsolete_data['beers'][0].name,
    expected_obsolete_data['beers'][0].name
)
```